# How do I make radiobuttons assign either a 0,1,2 or 3 to my variables?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**Here is a rough example of a multiple choice test that I made. It runs in terminal and I'm hoping to make a Graphical User Interface for it using Tkinter.**

```
print "CATEGORY 1: ANXIOUS FEELINGS"
print
print "1. Anxiety, nervousness, worry or fear"
BAI_var1 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")
print
print "2. Feeling that things around you are strange, unreal, or foggy"
BAI_var2 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")
print
print "3. Feeling detached from all or part of your body"
BAI_var3 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")

print "Depression Test"
print
print
print "1. Sadness: Have been feeling sad or down in the dumps?"
BDC_var1 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")
print
print "2. Discouragement: Does the future look hopeless?"
BDC_var2 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")
print
print "3. Low self-esteem: Do you feel worthless or think of yourself as a failure?"
BDC_var3 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")

#Burns Anxiety Inventory
#CATEGORY 1: ANXIOUS FEELINGS
Cat1_var = BAI_var1 + BAI_var2 + BAI_var3

#Burns Anxiety Checklist
BAI_var = Cat1_var
#Burns Depression Checklist
BDC_var = BDC_var1 + BDC_var2 + BDC_var3

#Prints your BAI & your BDC
print "Your BAI =", BAI_var,"Your BDC =", BDC_var


name = raw_input ("Please type in your name:")
bai = str(input("Please enter your BAI:"))
bdc = str(input("Please enter your BDC:"))
year = str(input("please enter the year:"))
month = str(input("Please enter the month:"))
day = str(input("Please enter day:"))
time_hour = str(input("Please enter the current hour:"))
time_minute = str(input("Please enter the current minutes:"))
am_pm = raw_input ("Please enter pm or am:")

file = open('Burns inventory 1.3.txt', 'a')
file.write(name + '\n')
file.write(day)
file.write("/")
file.write(month)
file.write("/")
file.write(year)
file.write('\n')
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your BAI is:')
file.write(bai)
file.write('\n')
file.write('Your BDC is:')
file.write(bdc)
file.write('\n')
file.write(time_hour)
file.write(':')
file.write(time_minute)
file.write('\n')
file.write(' ')
file.write(am_pm)
file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

**I have been working for 2 days two teach myself how to use Tkinter. My friend and I made this rough example of what the test might look like.**

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        w = Label(master, text="1. Anxiety, nervousness, worry or fear")
        w.pack()

        v = IntVar()
        Radiobutton(master, text="0 for not at all", variable=v, value=1).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
        Radiobutton(master, text="1 for somewhat", variable=v, value=2).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
        Radiobutton(master, text="2 for moderatly", variable=v, value=3).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
        Radiobutton(master, text="3 for a lot", variable=v, value=4).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")

        self.button = Button(master, text="BACK", fg="red", command=self.button6)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button = Button(master, text="NEXT", fg="red", command=self.button5)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    def button6(self):
        print "Sam is awesome!GAJONGA" 

    def button5(self):
        print "PYTHON FOR THE WIN! GIAN SAYS PYTHON = FILTHY" 

master = Tk()
app = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

I can think of a few goals with this Tkinter GUI:

- Make Radiobuttons assign either a 0,1,2 or 3 to my variables(BAI_var1, BAI_var2, BAI_3 etc.)
- Make the "NEXT" & "BACK" buttons show a different question every time you press it.
- Make a page at the end of the test that has multiple input fields for name, date, etc.

I did not make the test!! I only made the software. The test was designed by David Burns and is available in his work book "The Feeling Good Book".

Comment: If Bryan's answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark by his answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Ethan. I just did :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change all of the places where you have `v` with `self.v` so that it becomes an attribute of the object. You'll then see that it has whatever value is selected in the group of radiobuttons.

```
...
self.v = IntVar()
...
Radiobutton(master, text="1 for somewhat", variable=self.v, value=2)...
...
```

Once you do that, in your `button5` or `button6` method you can do `print self.v.get()` to see the value.

Comment: Thank you Bryan! You helped me :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in learning tkinter right now, [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) would be a good fit for quickly getting a GUI for this test.  It's not in the standard library, so you'll have to either install it with `pip install` or download it and put the easygui.py file in the same folder as your script.  Easygui lets you do things like:

```
import easygui
animal = easygui.choicebox(
        msg='Pick an animal.',
        title='answer the question',
        choices=('dog', 'cat', 'pig')
        )
print animal
# prints dog or pig or cat
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm running Python 2.5 on my iMac which is running OS X 10.6. I'm not sure how to intall either easygui or pip :-( Should I try to update Python?

Comment: Thomas, I just downloaded easygui. Where should I move it to so that I can use it?

Comment: @gian848396 If you haven't learned about the python path yet, just put it (the one .py file) in the same folder as your script.